# Need help translating an inherited excel formula to SQL or DAX

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, excel-formula, dax

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the logic in this inherited formula intended to calculate ASCVD risk. Data is processed (using fuzzy logic to match records) in an SQL database prior to being manipulated in PowerBI so if there is a preferred place to handle it I would be fine with either one.

```
=IF(
OR(
(AGE)<40, 
(AGE)>79, 
(TCRow)<130, 
(TCRow)>320, 
(HDLRow)<20, 
(HDLRow)>100, 
(BPSystolicRow)<90, 
(BPSystolicRow)>200, 
AND((DiabetesRow)="", 
(DiabetesRowNo)=""), 
AND((ONBPMEDICATIONROW)="", 
(OFFBPMEDICATIONROW)=""), 
AND((SmokerRow)="", 
(SmokingRowNo)="")), "", 
IFERROR(IF((GenderFemaleRow)=1, 1-0.9665^(EXP
(((SUM(LN((AGE))*-29.799, 
LN((AGE))^2*4.884, 
LN((TCRow))*13.54, 
LN((AGE))*LN((TCRow))*-3.114, 
LN((HDLRow))*-13.578, 
LN(D3)*LN((HDLRow))*3.149, 
IF((ONBPMEDICATIONROW)=1, 
ROUND(LN((BPSystolicRow))*2.019, 2), 
LN((BPSystolicRow))*1.957), 
IF((SmokerRow)=1, 7.574, 0), 
ROUND(LN((AGE))*IF((SmokerRow)=1, -1.665, 0), 3), 
IF((DiabetesRow)=1, 0.661, 0)))-(-29.18)))), 1-0.9144^(EXP((SUM(LN((AGE))*12.344, 
LN((TCRow))*11.853, 
LN((AGE))*LN((TCRow))*-2.664, 
LN((HDLRow))*-7.99, 
LN((AGE))*LN((HDLRow))*1.769, 
IF((ONBPMEDICATIONROW)=1, 
LN((BPSystolicRow))*1.797, 
LN((BPSystolicRow))*1.764), 
IF((SmokerRow)=1, 7.837, 0), 
IF((SmokerRow)=1, 
LN((AGE))*-1.795, 0), 
IF((DiabetesRow)=1, 0.658, 0))-(61.18))))), ""))
```

Comment: WOW.  Any documentation of what this is supposed to be doing?  I would be very reluctant to simply rely on it and try to translate it to something else, without a specification of the intended behavior.

Comment: @dan1111 especially since it looks like this is being used to prescribe diabetes medication to patients... really risky to convert this to another language without an explicit set of requirements or logic.

Comment: Not being used to prescribe anything... its being used to calculate risk for aggregated population analytics. Unfortunately I do not have any documentation on the process used to create this formula and cannot find any formulaic guidance on ASCVD risk on the internet.

Comment: If someone wrote a big mess like that with no documentation, rule #1 is *do not* assume that it is error-free.

Answer (score 2):

I'll have a go at it. In shorthand the formula says:

```
=IF(ParametersOutOfRangeOrMissing,"",CalculateRisk)
```

So if certain data are out of range or missing, return "", otherwise calculate the risk.

The `ParametersOutOfRangeOrMissing` is a check to make sure that all of the necessary data is available and that the data are within the range where the risk calculation is valid. It is a big `OR` statement that says this risk calculation doesn't apply if any one of a number of conditions are present (too young, too old, systolic blood pressure is too high or too low, etc.). This part of the formula is:

```
OR(
    (AGE)<40, (AGE)>79, 
    (TCRow)<130, (TCRow)>320, 
    (HDLRow)<20, (HDLRow)>100, 
    (BPSystolicRow)<90, (BPSystolicRow)>200, 
    AND(
        (DiabetesRow)="", (DiabetesRowNo)=""
    ), 
    AND(
         (ONBPMEDICATIONROW)="", (OFFBPMEDICATIONROW)=""
    ), 
    AND(
        (SmokerRow)="", (SmokingRowNo)="")
)
```

The `CalculateRisk` part of the formula is this:

```
CalculateRisk = IFERROR(AttemptRiskCalculation,"")
```

So return "" if any error occurs during the calculation, otherwise return the calculated risk.

`AttemptRiskCalculation` is gender-based:

```
IF((GenderFemaleRow)=1,FemaleRisk,MaleRisk)
```

Here I'm assuming that `(GenderFemaleRow)=1` means Female, but it could be Male.

The formulas for female and male risk are similar, but not the same. Here's the risk for females:

```
FemaleRisk=1-0.9665^(EXP(((SUM(
                               LN((AGE))*-29.799, 
                               LN((AGE))^2*4.884, 
                               LN((TCRow))*13.54, 
                               LN((AGE))*LN((TCRow))*-3.114, 
                               LN((HDLRow))*-13.578, 
                               LN(D3)*LN((HDLRow))*3.149, 
                               IF(
                                  (ONBPMEDICATIONROW)=1, 
                                  ROUND(LN((BPSystolicRow))*2.019, 2), 
                                  LN((BPSystolicRow))*1.957
                               ), 
                               IF((SmokerRow)=1, 7.574, 0), 
                               ROUND(LN((AGE))*IF((SmokerRow)=1, -1.665, 0), 3), 
                               IF((DiabetesRow)=1, 0.661, 0)
                           ))-(-29.18))))
```

And for males:

```
MaleRisk=1-0.9144^(EXP((SUM(
                            LN((AGE))*12.344, 
                            LN((TCRow))*11.853, 
                            LN((AGE))*LN((TCRow))*-2.664, 
                            LN((HDLRow))*-7.99, 
                            LN((AGE))*LN((HDLRow))*1.769, 
                            IF(
                               (ONBPMEDICATIONROW)=1, 
                               LN((BPSystolicRow))*1.797, 
                               LN((BPSystolicRow))*1.764
                            ), 
                            IF((SmokerRow)=1, 7.837, 0), 
                            IF((SmokerRow)=1, LN((AGE))*-1.795, 0), 
                            IF((DiabetesRow)=1, 0.658, 0)
                        )-(61.18))))
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Well done! Great job explaining it, and you have actually convinced me that my comments above are a bit too pessimistic.

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you for taking the time to answer!